# mysql default value errors on new server

Tags: php, mysql, default

I have a strange issue. I have copied PHP source code and MySQL database (phpMyAdmin standard export-import) from one server to another. On the old server everything worked fine but on the new server I have database errors.

> Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value

I know how to set the default value or need to pass value if `null is off`. But why did it work on the old server? Did I miss something during export-import? There are no triggers in the old database. Maybe the configuration is different?

Comment: Check the database table on both servers and see if there is actually a default set on either.

Comment: we can't look for code-problems without either your code or your database layout(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is most likely in `STRICT` mode. Try running

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=''
```

or edit your `my.cnf` to make sure you aren't setting `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` or the like.

OR, change table definition and add default value for the field.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableA` CHANGE `field` `field` TEXT NULL
```

or, give it a default value as empty string:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableA` CHANGE `field` `field` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```